# Longtable smaller size, less space between columns and lines

Tags: longtable

I created a table from a Stata output, which is longer than one page.
I used the package `longtable`, but the table is too long and width for the page and doesn't adjust. I want to have the table on one page. The spaces between columns or lines shouldn't be that large. If they can't be reduced, also smaller letters would be fine.

My minimal example is

```
\documentclass[
mediumheadings,  % kleinere {\"U}berschriften
liststotoc,     % listen in inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
twoside,
bibtotoc,       % literaturverzeichnis in inhltsvz. aufnehmen
headsepline,    % trennlinie unter kopfzeile
    12pt,
    parskip=half                        % ehemals 11pt
    ]{scrartcl}



\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} %Verwende deutsche, bzw. amerikanische Silbentrennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %damit k{\"o}nnen Umlaute ganz normal geschrieben werden. 
\usepackage{graphicx}     % zum einbinden von grafiken
\graphicspath{{grafiken/}{../}{kapitel/}} % da sind m{\"o}gliche bilder fuer den includegraphics-Befehl zu finden (man muss dann nicht den ganzen Pfad bei includegraphics angeben. 
\usepackage{multirow}     % fuer kompliziertere Tabellen
\usepackage{rotating}           % um senkrechte Tabellen zu produzieren
\usepackage{framed}             % Typesetting margin notes inside floats, footnotes, or frames
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrpage2}     % paket f{\"u}r kopf- und fu{\ss}zeilen
\pagestyle{plain}   % kopzeilenseitenstil
       % Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage{setspace}           % zum ändern das Zeilenabstands: \singlespacing (onehalfspacing,doublespacing)
\usepackage{url}          % fuer urls: schreibweise ist z. B. \url{http://www.uni-mannheim.de}
\usepackage{color}              % damit man die Schriftfarbe ändern kann
\usepackage{eurosym}            % zur Ausgabe von € mit \euro{} oder \EUR{08.15}
%\usepackage[left]{eurosym} %falls man das Symbol links haben will.
%\usepackage{diagbox}           % für Tabellen mit Diagonalen Strichen in den Zelle 
\usepackage{slashbox}           % wurde durch auf Macs schon durch das mordernere diagbox-Paket ersetzt
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % damit die Trennungshilfe mit Umlauten funktioniert! Schrift zu unscharf
\usepackage[savemem]{listings} %Paket um LIstings sauber zu formatieren.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
%Das Paket erzeugt ein anklickbares Verzeichnis in der PDF-Datei.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{listings} % makes including of Stata Code possible
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\lstloadlanguages{TeX}    % Listing Definationen für PHP Code
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    postbreak=\space,
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor}}
\newenvironment{ListChanges}%
    {\begin{list}{$\diamondsuit$}{}}%
    {\end{list}}
\setlength{\parindent}{5pt} 
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries}
\automark{section}
% -
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\begin{document}  % dokument f{\"a}ngt an
\selectlanguage{english} %deutsche Silbentrennung
{
    \singlespacing
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}%
    \centering
    \addtolength\tabcolsep{-.35em}% 
    \small
\captionof{table}{Regression of Average Age of Devices as Energy Efficiency}
\label{aadreg}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         \\
    \midrule
    LogInc    &  -0.0976\sym{***}&  -0.0678\sym{***}&  -0.0593\sym{**} &  -0.0643\sym{**} &  -0.0582\sym{**} &  -0.0461         \\
    &  (-4.03)         &  (-2.72)         &  (-2.36)         &  (-2.25)         &  (-2.01)         &  (-1.56)         \\
    \addlinespace
    Nwhite    & -0.00778\sym{***}&-0.000972         & -0.00146         & -0.00117         & -0.00124         &-0.000485         \\
    &  (-3.37)         &  (-0.35)         &  (-0.53)         &  (-0.46)         &  (-0.50)         &  (-0.19)         \\
    \addlinespace
    NTVPC     & -0.00327         & -0.00237         & -0.00113         & -0.00238         & -0.00301         & -0.00239         \\
    &  (-0.78)         &  (-0.56)         &  (-0.27)         &  (-0.54)         &  (-0.67)         &  (-0.54)         \\
    \addlinespace
    owner     &    0.182\sym{***}&    0.106\sym{***}&    0.114\sym{***}&    0.127\sym{***}&    0.128\sym{***}&    0.130\sym{***}\\
    &   (7.13)         &   (3.80)         &   (4.02)         &   (4.38)         &   (4.40)         &   (4.47)         \\
    \addlinespace
    Npers     &                  &  -0.0326\sym{**} &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
    &                  &  (-2.37)         &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
    \addlinespace
    age       &                  &   0.0183\sym{***}&   0.0191\sym{***}&   0.0216\sym{***}&   0.0220\sym{***}&   0.0224\sym{***}\\
    &                  &   (3.31)         &   (3.34)         &   (3.55)         &   (3.58)         &   (3.65)         \\
    \addlinespace
    age2      &                  &-0.000105\sym{**} &-0.000106\sym{*}  &-0.000130\sym{**} &-0.000135\sym{**} &-0.000144\sym{**} \\
    &                  &  (-2.05)         &  (-1.92)         &  (-2.18)         &  (-2.23)         &  (-2.38)         \\
    \addlinespace
    env       &                  &   0.0955\sym{***}&   0.0971\sym{***}&   0.0895\sym{***}&   0.0899\sym{***}&   0.0884\sym{***}\\
    &                  &   (3.21)         &   (3.26)         &   (2.89)         &   (2.89)         &   (2.84)         \\
    \addlinespace
    kids      &                  &                  &  0.00317         &                  &                  &                  \\
    &                  &                  &   (0.18)         &                  &                  &                  \\
    \addlinespace
    adults    &                  &                  &  -0.0629\sym{***}&  -0.0578\sym{***}&  -0.0591\sym{***}&  -0.0266         \\
    &                  &                  &  (-3.57)         &  (-3.18)         &  (-3.24)         &  (-1.17)         \\
    \addlinespace
    elder     &                  &                  &  -0.0703\sym{**} &  -0.0685\sym{**} &  -0.0698\sym{**} &  -0.0399         \\
    &                  &                  &  (-2.47)         &  (-2.28)         &  (-2.31)         &  (-0.95)         \\
    \addlinespace
    plan      &                  &                  &                  &  -0.0153\sym{**} &  -0.0162\sym{***}&  -0.0142\sym{**} \\
    &                  &                  &                  &  (-2.55)         &  (-2.67)         &  (-2.36)         \\
    \addlinespace
    educ      &                  &                  &                  &   0.0442\sym{*}  &   0.0469\sym{*}  &   0.0447\sym{*}  \\
    &                  &                  &                  &   (1.67)         &   (1.77)         &   (1.69)         \\
    \addlinespace
    migback   &                  &                  &                  &  -0.0781\sym{*}  &  -0.0811\sym{*}  &                  \\
    &                  &                  &                  &  (-1.71)         &  (-1.78)         &                  \\
    \addlinespace
    PriceSen  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   0.0198         &                  \\
    &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (1.58)         &                  \\
    \addlinespace
    LonPar    &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.168\sym{*}  \\
    &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (1.85)         \\
    \addlinespace
    alone     &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.103\sym{**} \\
    &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (2.08)         \\
    \addlinespace
    OnlyOld   &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   0.0443         \\
    &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (0.71)         \\
    \addlinespace
    \_cons    &    3.182\sym{***}&    2.304\sym{***}&    2.241\sym{***}&    2.194\sym{***}&    2.127\sym{***}&    1.936\sym{***}\\
    &  (17.27)         &  (10.12)         &   (9.70)         &   (8.85)         &   (8.49)         &   (7.37)         \\
    \midrule
    \(N\)     &     2451         &     2363         &     2363         &     2174         &     2165         &     2174         \\
    \(R^{2}\) &    0.030         &    0.073         &    0.076         &    0.082         &    0.083         &    0.085         \\
    F         &    18.23         &    22.87         &    18.59         &    15.23         &    14.09         &    14.01         \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best, Fabian

Comment: Welcome! Don't put it in a `table`. That makes it a float and floats cannot break across pages. Just `\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}` will work.

Comment: If I just put the caption into longtable and then delete everything before begin and end {longtable}, there are a lot of error logs and it doesnt work any more :/

Comment: Use `caption` or `capt-of` and the `\captionof{table}{My caption}` command.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that is not working. In every line there is the error log "undefined control sequence" . something is missing

Comment: I found it out, the line with /def was neccesarry. Do you also know how I can reduce the space between lines and columns?

Comment: You can change the length `\tabcolsep`, for example. Or you can put `@{}` between columns to kill the separation altogether. However, your table will be harder to read. I don't recommend reducing the separation between rows as this is already too little in a standard document. It is recommended to increase this, rather than decreasing it, for readability. If you posted a complete example, it would be easier because something may be increasing the separation but it isn't possible to know that from the fragment you've posted.

Comment: ok, i did in a below. hope it's not too long. And thanks already for your help!

Comment: your example should be in the question (and should be a complete document so people can use it) not in the answer, but the version in the answer the code declares three columns `l*{2}c` but  the image is from an unrelated 8 column table so what are you trying to show there? an extra 1em vertical space is added between each row by `\\[1em]` perhaps you want to delete the `[1em]` ?

Comment: Note that without a complete example, we don't know how much space your have. 'Too wide' for what? 'More than one page' of what? A4? A5? US letter? Margins?

Comment: I changed it now, sorry for the inconvenience. the admin asked me to edit it and not post it as an answer. Hope the example is helping. I want to have the table on one page if possible (A4)

Comment: By the way, to format a block of code, highlight it and press the `{}` button on the editing bar or use ctrl+k.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility although it could do with some further TLC, I think. I have used `\small`, reduced the separation between columns and eliminated the `1em` of spacing between many rows. (There just isn't room if this has to go on a page and it was not really helping legibility.) I've used `booktabs` to get a little extra spacing, and replaced the `\hline`s with appropriate rules from that package. If the table needs to fit on a page, then `longtable` is pointless.

I've also done a little editing of the preamble. Mostly, I removed stuff to minimise the example. When I've removed things for other reasons, I've commented the line and annotated it instead. `epsfig` and `subfigure` are obsolete, for example, and ought not be used whereas `graphicx` was simply unneeded.

I've also used Koma's options in some cases to replace manual settings or other packages. I recommend seeing if you can expand on this e.g. by replacing `geometry`. (Maybe you really can't but you should know why if that's the case, so that you understand the costs.)

```
\documentclass[
mediumheadings,  % kleinere {\"U}berschriften
liststotoc,     % listen in inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
twoside,
bibtotoc,       % literaturverzeichnis in inhltsvz. aufnehmen
headsepline,    % trennlinie unter kopfzeile
12pt,                        % ehemals 11pt
parskip=half,   % better than setting it manually
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} %Verwende deutsche, bzw. amerikanische Silbentrennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %damit k{\"o}nnen Umlaute ganz normal geschrieben werden.
% \usepackage{subfigure}      % OBSOLETE: do NOT use
%\usepackage{epsfig}         % OBSOLETE: do NOT use
\usepackage{multirow}     % fuer kompliziertere Tabellen
\usepackage{rotating}           % um senkrechte Tabellen zu produzieren
\usepackage{scrpage2}     % paket f{\"u}r kopf- und fu{\ss}zeilen
\pagestyle{plain}   % kopzeilenseitenstil
% Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage{setspace}           % zum ändern das Zeilenabstands: \singlespacing (onehalfspacing,doublespacing)
\usepackage{eurosym}            % zur Ausgabe von € mit \euro{} oder \EUR{08.15}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % damit die Trennungshilfe mit Umlauten funktioniert! Schrift zu unscharf
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{5pt}              % Gibt das das Einrücken am Anfang eines neuen Absatzes an
\onehalfspacing %setzt den Zeilenabstand auf 1,5pt
\begin{document}  % dokument f{\"a}ngt an
  \selectlanguage{english} %deutsche Silbentrennung
  \newpage
  {%
    \singlespacing
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}%
    \centering
    \addtolength\tabcolsep{-.35em}%
    \small
    \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
      \toprule
      &1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
      \midrule
      LogInc    &  -0.0716\sym{**} &  -0.0629\sym{*}  &  -0.0554\sym{*}  &  -0.0547         &  -0.0565\sym{*}  &  -0.0482         &  -0.0392         \\
      &  (-2.94)         &  (-2.53)         &  (-2.21)         &  (-1.91)         &  (-1.98)         &  (-1.67)         &  (-1.33)         \\

      Nwhite    & -0.00113         & -0.00104         & -0.00146         & -0.00109         & -0.00112         & -0.00118         &-0.000384         \\
      &  (-0.42)         &  (-0.38)         &  (-0.53)         &  (-0.44)         &  (-0.44)         &  (-0.47)         &  (-0.15)         \\

      NTVPC     & -0.00236         & -0.00181         &-0.000389         & -0.00175         & -0.00155         & -0.00238         & -0.00154         \\
      &  (-0.56)         &  (-0.43)         &  (-0.09)         &  (-0.39)         &  (-0.35)         &  (-0.53)         &  (-0.35)         \\

      Npers     &  -0.0607\sym{***}&  -0.0295\sym{*}  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &  (-4.86)         &  (-2.15)         &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\

      owner     &    0.182\sym{***}&    0.112\sym{***}&    0.120\sym{***}&    0.134\sym{***}&    0.134\sym{***}&    0.135\sym{***}&    0.137\sym{***}\\
      &   (7.17)         &   (4.01)         &   (4.27)         &   (4.64)         &   (4.64)         &   (4.66)         &   (4.74)         \\

      age       &                  &  0.00717\sym{***}&  0.00849\sym{***}&  0.00868\sym{***}&  0.00855\sym{***}&  0.00866\sym{***}&  0.00818\sym{***}\\
      &                  &   (7.25)         &   (6.56)         &   (6.61)         &   (6.52)         &   (6.55)         &   (6.02)         \\

      env       &                  &   0.0975\sym{**} &   0.0992\sym{***}&   0.0918\sym{**} &   0.0912\sym{**} &   0.0921\sym{**} &   0.0906\sym{**} \\
      &                  &   (3.29)         &   (3.35)         &   (2.96)         &   (2.95)         &   (2.96)         &   (2.92)         \\

      kids      &                  &                  &  0.00409         &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &   (0.23)         &                  &                  &                  &                  \\

      adults    &                  &                  &  -0.0579\sym{***}&  -0.0535\sym{**} &  -0.0524\sym{**} &  -0.0545\sym{**} &  -0.0249         \\
      &                  &                  &  (-3.31)         &  (-2.97)         &  (-2.91)         &  (-3.02)         &  (-1.10)         \\

      elder     &                  &                  &  -0.0809\sym{**} &  -0.0846\sym{**} &  -0.0829\sym{**} &  -0.0863\sym{**} &  -0.0469         \\
      &                  &                  &  (-2.88)         &  (-2.87)         &  (-2.82)         &  (-2.91)         &  (-1.11)         \\

      plan      &                  &                  &                  &  -0.0148\sym{*}  &  -0.0150\sym{*}  &  -0.0157\sym{**} &  -0.0138\sym{*}  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &  (-2.47)         &  (-2.49)         &  (-2.59)         &  (-2.30)         \\

      educ      &                  &                  &                  &   0.0388         &   0.0396         &   0.0414         &   0.0396         \\
      &                  &                  &                  &   (1.46)         &   (1.50)         &   (1.56)         &   (1.50)         \\

      migback   &                  &                  &                  &                  &  -0.0803         &                  &                  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &  (-1.75)         &                  &                  \\

      PriceSen  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   0.0200         &                  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (1.60)         &                  \\

      LonPar    &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.177         \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (1.95)         \\

      alone     &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &    0.102\sym{*}  \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (2.05)         \\

      OnlyOld   &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &  0.00879         \\
      &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &   (0.14)         \\

      \_cons    &    3.039\sym{***}&    2.525\sym{***}&    2.445\sym{***}&    2.400\sym{***}&    2.423\sym{***}&    2.339\sym{***}&    2.202\sym{***}\\
      &  (16.57)         &  (12.71)         &  (12.25)         &  (10.89)         &  (10.99)         &  (10.45)         &   (9.33)         \\
      \midrule
      \(N\)     &     2451         &     2363         &     2363         &     2174         &     2174         &     2165         &     2174         \\
      \(R^{2}\) &    0.039         &    0.071         &    0.075         &    0.079         &    0.080         &    0.079         &    0.082         \\
      adj. \(R~\)&    0.037         &    0.068         &    0.071         &    0.075         &    0.075         &    0.074         &    0.076         \\
      F         &    19.37         &    25.48         &    20.18         &    17.28         &    15.93         &    15.64         &    14.33         \\
      \bottomrule
      \multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
      \multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
    \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular on page]

Comment: thank you. It is a lot better, but does still not look like your screenshot. I used booktabs in stata, and copied the commands of your before table.
I didnt delete all the packages you recommended, cause I needed some.
Now my table looks like this: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screen1xszpvfgdoa.jpg
It's a lot better , but still too long. And the caption I created by `captionof`is not on the same page.

Comment: the best thing would if it totally adjust to the page side. Now there it exceeds the space on the bottom

Comment: @FabianKT I'm afraid I can't view your screenshot as my institution considers the site on which it is hosted to be too high risk. As you can tell, it fits on the page in my example. Hard to say why you get different results. Try to figure out what is changing the page layout dimensions/font size/spacing in your case. As to the packages: mostly I just deleted them to minimise the code. Only the ones I left in commented form are ones which you shouldn't be using. Basically, don't use `epsfig` and don't use `subfigure`. You can't need the first. Use `subfig` or `subcaption` for sub-figures.

Comment: new upload: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B18Ip0Q2E0pKR2JrdXVGalZLQnM/view
is there a similar command to set the space between two lines?
or a command that the table just fits the text wide and length?

Comment: @FabianKT Did you use `\singlespacing`? Did you delete the setting of `\parskip` and use the class option? (Not sure if the latter would matter or not without checking the code.) You can scale a box to whatever size you want. However, doing so is Evil.

Comment: yes I did all three. If there is no other option, how can I do the evil thing? ;)
do you want me to send you the code again?

Comment: I found out the problem is inside the table, not the environment. If I take my table created by stata with booktab and include, keeping everything the same (I included just the begin{tabular} part), it just shows again the large spaces and not your table. If I take your table and put it in my environment, it also displayed as in your screenshot

Comment: @FabianKT Does it all those `[1em]`s? If so, yes, you need to remove those. Those are adding 1em of additional space every time they occur.

Comment: yes but i dont know where they come from. can i send you my code again somehow?

Comment: @FabianKT You can edit your question, sure. But you just delete the `[1em]` occurrences in the code. If you are talking about how to prevent statistical software producing code which includes them, then, I'm sorry but I have no idea. I had never heard of Stata before your question and still have no idea what it is or what it does.

Comment: Ok, I edit it again, I hope you can run it. 
Sorry, I misunderstood you. There is no [1em] in the code, but the space still appears.

Comment: @FabianKT Remove the `\addlinespace` commands. They are adding the space.